# How to use directive for external link in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a angular 8 application. And there is a possibility to enter a link.

But you have two kind of links:

internal and external. with external I mean outside the domain of the site. For example: http://www.ad.nl

Then if a user click on that link the user has to be redirected to other tab with that link.

But you can also have a internal link: like this: http://localhost:4200/gezondheid/Measurement/actieindex

But then the link has to be opening in the same tab.

I have a directive for it like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appExternalLink]'
})

/**
 * This directive is responsible for checking if in Activity the link is a external link - then it wil open
 * in a seperate tab or is the link an internal(same domain) link, then it will open in the same tab
 */
export class ExternalLinkDirective {

  @HostBinding('attr.rel') relAttr = '';
  @HostBinding('attr.target') targetAttr = '';
  @HostBinding('attr.href') hrefAttr = '';
  @Input() href: string;

  /**
   * Check if liink is external or not
   */
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.hrefAttr = this.href;

    if (this.isLinkExternal()) {
      this.relAttr = 'noopener';
      this.targetAttr = '_blank';
    }
  }

  /**
   * if link is external, then set the rel and target attributes
   */
  private isLinkExternal() {
    return !this.href.includes(location.hostname);
  }
```

and I inject it in the component like this:

```
 <a appExternalLink
      *ngIf="activity.link; else nolink"
      [href]="activity.link">
      <div class="todo-day-part-subject">{{ activity.subject }}</div>
      <div class="todo-day-part-block">
        <div class="todo-day-part-icon {{ getIcon(activity.type) }}"></div>
        <div class="todo-day-part-content">
          <div class="todo-day-part-text">{{ activity.text }}</div>
          <div class="todo-day-part-time">{{ activity.beginDate | date: 'HH:mm' }}</div>
          <div *ngIf="activity.link" class="todo-day-part-readmore">Bekijk</div>
          <div *ngIf="activity.state === 'Done'" class="todo-day-part-status-signal">
            <span class="fa fa-check-circle"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
```

But it works for now fo intern link. But if the link is: http://www.ad.nl then it will open in the same tab en not in a seperate tab.

So what I have to change?

Thank you

Comment: Is it opening ` http://www.ad.nl` in the same tab?

Comment: yes, and not in seperate tab

Comment: add `target="_blank"`

Comment: What exactly  do you mean?

Comment: This `<a  href="http://www.adl.com" target="_blank"></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first off, with internal link, I guess you do not mean a link that's inside the angular app, because for that you have to use `[routerLink]`. If it's just to a different page outside of the angular app but inside the same domain, I believe you should do the following:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'a[appExternalLink]'
})
export class ExternalLinkDirective {

  @HostBinding('rel')
  rel = '';

  @HostBinding('target')
  target = '_self';

  @Input()
  @HostBinding('href')
  href?: string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.href) {
      const isExternal = this.isLinkExternal();
      this.rel = isExternal ? 'noopener' : '';
      this.target = isExternal ? '_blank' : '_self';
    }
  }

  /**
   * Check if link is external or not
   */
  private isLinkExternal() {
    return !(this.href || '').includes(location.hostname);
  }
}
```

This basically means, don't use the `attr.` binding, because that doesn't work in this case :) You need to update the property, not just the attribute.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cso9nn)

Comment: HI, yes, that was my other question. Where to put the routerLink? so that it will not be a reload

Comment: for that you should not add the protocol `http://`, and you cannot do it with such a directive. You should probably use a component and make it show an anchor tag with routerLink or href depending on the components href input. You can then use <ng-content> to show the actual link text

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfcyxz) of how else you could solve this task

The idea is to prevent default behavior of link tags and resolve routing via javascript.

Also, you dont need to know about link type on every ngOnChanges fire. So you can check it only on click event and make decision where to route your customer.

Comment: The issue with this is that if the user tabs to a link, and presses enter, the click won't get triggered. Nevertheless it's another way to do it. About the `ngOnChanges`, you just need to add a `if(changes.href)` to make it change only when necessary

Comment: Try to paste the GIST here

Comment: @PierreDuc, you are right, but the issue you mentioned could be solved by adding a listener to enter keyup